# What voltage and current do I need to charge a 4V Acid Battery?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lead-acid

I need to charge a 4V Lead Acid battery, but it is not clear what charging current and voltage I need.

I checked many datasheets for 4V acid batteries, but I did not find anything that determines what voltage and current I need to charge it.

Is 2-3V and about 400mA enough to charge this? http://www.allbatteries.co.uk/media/pdf/AMP92108_FR.pdf

Comment: No. You need a higher voltage than the battery. You haven't supplied any other details such as battery chemistry, Ah capacity or links to datasheets so you aren't going to get many answers.

Comment: I uploaded the datasheet of the battery i want to use

Answer (score 4):

From the datasheet you linked:

[image]

Comment: So is this the minimum voltage and current to start charging the battery? So if i supplied a lower voltage and current than that in the spec sheet, will the battery not charge? or will it charge but on a slower rate?

Comment: It's the recommended charge voltage. Lower won't charge. Higher will risk damage to battery, personnel and property. The power supply should be capable of 0.85 A. Less will do but charging will take longer. Battery is 3.4 Ah so charge time will be \$ \frac {Ah}{A} = \frac{3.4}{.85}h \$.

Comment: 4.55V looks like the float charge level--charging at that level will not cause the batt to achieve a proper saturation charge & likely lead to sulfation problems.

Answer (score 3):

re:  "Is 2-3V and about 400mA enough to charge this?"
No, charging at that V is too low.  The batt will never charge to full saturation (which is ideal for LA batts).  If you only charge it to that level, the lead-sulfate crystals will eventually harden & prevent the batt from being able to be recharged (which will essentially ruin the batt). Instead, do the following.  It is based on the datasheet that you provided.  Ideally, you will use a regulated bench power supply to charge your batt properly.

1. **For the CV/CC (constant voltage/constant current) charging period:**

   - limit max V to: 4.84V (±3%) (Note: As the batt charges, V will increase to this level--if the batt is good)
   - limit max current to: 0.8575A (Note: As the batt charges, current will decrease from this level--if the batt is good)
2. **For the float (maintenance) charging period (i.e. when batt V = 4.84V (±3%) & the charge current has fallen to ~300mA):**

   - limit max V to: 4.55V (±1%)
   - limit max current to: (not applicable.  The batt can remain at this V indefinitely without any problem.)

**Batt info:**
**Vnom** = 4 (i.e.: the nominal V of the batt)
 **Vrest** = ~4.22 (i.e.: the batt V after resting for 24hrs, SOC=100%)
  **Vtop** = 4.7 to 4.98 (i.e.: the max batt V at full saturation)
**Vfloat** = 4.5 to 4.59 (i.e.: the max batt V during maintenance charging)

hth, best regards!